# Angular 2 com jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

Eai pessoal,
eu queria saber se o uso do jquery junto com o angular2 é recomendado, ou o angular ja tem funções nativas pra manipulação do DOM assim como jquery?

o meu caso eu queria pra uma tarefa simples. Só alterar a altura de uma div:

```
var content = jQuery("#content");
var window_h = jQuery(window).height();
var top_bar_h = jQuery(".top-bar").innerHeight();
var nav_bar_h = jQuery(".nav-bar").innerHeight();

var content_h = window_h - (nav_bar_h + top_bar_h);
content.height(content_h);
```

existe alguma forma de eu fazer isso usando somente o angular2?
vlw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora seja a principal função do Angular manipular a estrutura da página (DOM) de acordo com os dados (*data-bindind*), ele não possui em sua [API](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/index.html) funcionalidades para cálculo de aspectos visuais.

Então, basicamente, você é livre para utilizar qualquer outra biblioteca, inclusive jQuery, para realizar outros tipos de operações como manipulação de certos estilos, contanto que você não manipule a estrutura do documento.

Entretanto, há uma "pegadinha" ou problema nisso. Manipular estilos dessa forma irá adicionar CSS *inline* na tag HTML, então se o Angular atualizar aquele elemento em algum momento, ele vai perder esse estilo adicionado manualmente. A solução é calcular a altura sempre que atualizar o elemento ou arranjar outra forma de definir a altura.

Comment: obgd pela resposta @utluiz